# Can we use trimmer for pubic and shaving head?

Tags: practical-islam

Is it permissible to use a beard trimmer to remove Pubic hair? I m in medina and going for second umrah. I wanted to find if I can use same clippers to shave my head after umrah which has been used to remove pubic hair?